# Why is $ \frac{\ln(y_n/y_0)}{\ln(1+r)} = \frac{\log(y_n/y_0)}{\log(1+r)} $?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I can see that the results of two calculations:

$$ \frac{\ln(\frac{y_n}{y_0})}{\ln(1+r)} = \frac{\log(\frac{y_n}{y_0})}{\log(1+r)} $$

are equal, however, I am struggling to understand exactly why, as I would expect the two log and ln to have different function results?

Comment: By $\log$ do you mean by $\log_{10}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because logarithms with different bases differ by a constant factor.

Let $a, b, x > 0$, with $a, b \neq 1$.  Then the [Change of Base Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logarithmic_identities#Changing_the_base) states that
$$\log_a x = \frac{\log_b x}{\log_b a}$$
If we set $a = 10$ and $b = e$, we obtain
$$\frac{\log\left(\frac{y_n}{y_0}\right)}{\log(1 + r)} = \frac{\dfrac{\ln\left(\frac{y_n}{y_0}\right)}{\ln 10}}{\dfrac{\ln (1 + r)}{\ln 10}} = \frac{\ln\left(\frac{y_n}{y_0}\right)}{\ln (1 + r)}$$

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with the following identity?
$$\log_a b \log_b c = \log _a c \tag 1$$
If not, the proof is as follows. Set $p=\log_a b$ and $q=\log_b c$. Then, by the definition of a logarithm, $a^p=b$ and $b^q=c$. Combine these to give $a^{pq}=b^q=c$ and the result follows.

Now rearrange (1) to get
$$\dfrac{\log_a c}{ \log_a b }= \log _b c \tag 2$$
and we see that the expression on the left of (2) is independent of $a$ (because it doesn't appear on the rhs). Your result follows immediately.

Answer (score 0):

$a:=y_n/y_0 >0,$ and $b:=(1+r)>0$, $b\not=1;$

$x_1:= \ln(a);$

Then $e^{x_1}=a$, and taking $\log$ of both sides:

$x_1\log (e) = \log (a);$

Likewise:

$x_2:=\ln (b)$ implies

$x_2 \log (e) =\log (b);$

$\dfrac{x_1}{x_2}=\dfrac{\log (a)}{\log (b)}$, and we are done.